# IMAP losing e-mails on sync

Tags: imap, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have two instances of Outlook 2013 (separate machines) connecting to IMAP mailbox.
Steps to reproduce are:

1. Delete one message from instance 1
2. In a few hours start instance 2 and delete different message.
3. Go back to instance 1 and realize that totally different messages disappeared + those deleted in step 1 & 2.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It seemed like an issue with Outlook 2013 implementation of IMAP.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I've found is a bit odd.
Basically set up my Hotmail account to download my e-mail and then Outlook 2013 would use EAS to download my e-mail from m.hotmail.com

The only downside is that I've got up to 30min. delay when receiving e-mails as that's the current limitation of Hotmail service for downloading external account e-mails.